# Google map code does not work on android - no map

Tags: android, html, css, google-maps, iframe

I revised the Google maps embed code to make it responsive to phones, thinking that that was the problem. However, after making it responsive, the map still doesn't show up on android or iPhone. The code is below. Could anyone help me figure out how to make it show up on phones?

```css
.embed-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='embed-container'>
    <iframe src='https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=zxAFpdy2LkIo.kbe-u_jjzDKw' width='800' height='400'></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the size of your map. take out the size styling from the iframe and put it in a media query. if `width` and `height` are half of what they are now  (i.e `400px` and `200px` ) it'll show up ok on phones - not iphones though, you'd have to go to `320px` for apple)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpfcfyg6/)